# No puedo modificar ni eliminar pero si agregar :,(

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

**Buenas amigos, verán tengo un problema al momento de tratar modificar y eliminar un registro en un formulario php con Mysql, no me marca error o algo por el estilo, pero no sucede nada, pero al agregar uno nuevo todo sale bien :(**

Adjunto código de la base de datos:

```
CREATE DATABASE u270474283_DBadmon;
CREATE TABLE `maing` (
`ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
`Nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Telefono` mediumtext NOT NULL,
`Telefono_Secundario` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
`Direccion` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
`Colonia` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Entre_Calles` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Municipio` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Es` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Codigo del formulario para modificar registro:

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM maing WHERE ID = '$id'";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="update.php" autocomplete="off">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="Nom" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nombre" name="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $row['Nombre']; ?>" >
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label for="Tel" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefono</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Telefono" name="Telefono" placeholder="Telelefono Principal" value="<?php echo $row['Telefono']; ?>" required>
</div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" />

<div class="form-group">
<label for="Tel" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefono Secundario</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Telefono_Secundario" name="Telefono_Secundario" placeholder="Telefono Secundario" value="<?php echo $row['Telefono_Secundario']; ?>" >
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="Dir" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Direccion</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Direccion" name="Direccion" placeholder="Direccion" value="<?php echo $row['Direccion']; ?>" >
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="Col" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Colonia</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Colonia" name="Colonia" placeholder="Colonia" value="<?php echo $row['Colonia']; ?>" >
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="Col" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Entre Calles</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Entre Calles" name="Entre_Calles" placeholder="Entre Calles" value="<?php echo $row['Entre_Calles']; ?>" >
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="Col" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Municipio</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Municipio" name="Mun" placeholder="Municipio" value="<?php echo $row['Municipio']; ?>" >
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="Col" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Es</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Es" name="es" placeholder="Es" value="<?php echo $row['Es']; ?>" >
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="Col" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Status</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Sta" name="Status" placeholder="Status" value="<?php echo $row['Status']; ?>" >
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Regresar</a>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Código de la función que modifica el registro

```
<?php

require 'conexion.php';

$id = $_POST['ID'];
$nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$telefono = $_POST['Telefono'];
$telefono2 = $_POST['Telelefono_Secundario'];
$direccion = $_POST['Direccion'];
$colonia = $_POST['Colonia'];
$entrecalles = $_POST['Entre_Calles'];
$municipio = $_POST['Municipio'];
$es = $_POST['Es'];
$status = $_POST['Status'];



$sql = "UPDATE `maing` SET `Nombre`='$nombre', `Telefono`='$telefono', `Telefono_Secundario`='$telefono2', `Direccion`='$direccion', `Colonia`='$colonia', `Entre_Calles`='$entrecalles', `Municipio` ='$municipio', `Es`='$es', `Status`='$status' WHERE `maing`.`ID` = '$id'";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

?>

<?php
if($resultado) { ?>
<h3>REGISTRO MODIFICADO</h3>
<?php } else { ?>
<h3>ERROR AL MODIFICAR</h3>
<?php }
?>
```

Código para eliminar un registro

```
<?php

require 'conexion.php';

$id = $_GET['ID'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM maing WHERE ID = '$id'";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

?>
<?php if($resultado) { ?>
<h3>REGISTRO ELIMINADO</h3>
<?php } else { ?>
<h3>ERROR AL ELIMINAR</h3>
<?php } ?>
```

**Ayudaaa, ya intente cambiar el nombre de los campos del formulario, cambiar el nombre de los campos de la base de datos y nada, como comentaba al ejecutar el código no me sale error, pero no sucede nada :,(**

Comment: De entrada veo que en tu parte de `UPDATE` y `DELETE` intentas recoger el valor del Id de un modo distinto, por ejemplo: `$id = $_POST['ID'];` mientras que en el `SELECT` usas `$id = $_GET['id'];` Entonces: (**1**). Usa siempre el método del formulario, no mezcles nunca `$_GET` con `$_POST`, a veces funciona, pero no todos los servidores permiten esa mezcla. (**2**). Usa la clave tal y como está en el formulario, si es `id` usa `id` si es `ID` usa `ID`, las claves de array son *case sensitive* en PHP. Corrige esos dos aspectos en todo tu código y ya nos cuentas.

Comment: Saca las comillas simple en id (en las querys), id es un número, estos van si comillas